# php preg replace numbers

Tags: php, string, numbers, preg-replace

I'm trying to build a preg replace for numbers in my script.

Let's have this example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer lobortis luctus scelerisque. Curabitur 3214567890 dignissim finibus felis,
vitae vehicula ipsum vehicula a. 
Maecenas tincidunt et metus vitae eleifend. Cras tellus eros, placerat 
https://www.facebook.com/groups/123456789123456789/
```

I have to find a number that it's write on a text source that 99% starts with 3 and it has 10 digits.

I wrote this simple preg_replace

```
preg_replace('/3[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})/e', '"Number" . md5("$0") . " " . "["."$1"."]"', data)
```

because I need to replace that number with md5 and write last 3 digits.

For example if I have 3214567890 I need to get

```
Number89467086c22e2cee9aae8dbf9c7f7453 [890]
```

That preg_replace did the work but it has 1 problem.

The problem I found few days ago is that if in source I have a link with a lot of numbers, for example, a facebook link

```
https://www.facebook.com/groups/123456789123456789/
```

preg_replace elaborates it too and replace numbers of that link, but I don't need to touch links, I need to convert only separated numbers.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try adding \s? If all numbers are separated from other text using space characters, that may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use word boundaries `\b`:

```
'~\b3[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})\b~'
```

or lookarounds `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` (to match only if not enclosed with other digits):

```
'~(?<!\d)3[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})(?!\d)~'
```

Or, if you want to only match the numbers when enclosed with whitespace symbols, use

```
'~(?<!\S)3[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})(?!\S)~'
```

Then, inside the code, you'd better use `preg_replace_callback` since `/e` modifier is deprecated:

```
preg_replace_callback('~(?<!\d)3[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})(?!\d)~', function($m) {
     return 'Number' . md5($m[0]) . ' [' . $m[1] . ']';
   }, data);
```

Comment: It works, but I found another problem: it convert if it found link like this: http://www.domain.com/Page/?num=3711436157

Comment: Ok, do you want to only match inside whitespaces? Use `'~(?<!\S)3[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})(?!\S)~'`